# Vuejs how to prevent form submit on enter but still save work in inputs?

Tags: forms, vue.js

This prevent enter submit,but at the moment prevent enter in inputs.
I need that enterkey work in inputs but not submit form.

```
<template id="form-template">
       <form action="save-passport" @keypress.enter.prevent method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"   >
<input type="submit" v-show="loaded"  v-on:click="saveForm" value="Save" />

<input type="text" required="required" name="field-11" > 
<select required="required" name="field-13"><option value=""></option> 
</select>
</form>
       </template>
```

Comment: maybe `@submit.prevent` ?

Comment: Do you want a newline on pressing enter instead of submitting the form?

Comment: To wastex but i don't want prevent submit i want prevent submit on enter.

Comment: To Vamsi i want this when some field filled with data(or deleted data) and it accepted with pressing enter another field would hide or show.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem.  Solution I did was to put the submit method on the opening form tag.  Then **no need** for the input/button type="submit" inside the form at the bottom.

```
<form class="form" action="" method="POST" @submit.enter.prevent="createForm()">
```

Also other options available on inputs:

```
@keydown.enter.prevent
@keyup.enter.prevent
@submit.enter.prevent
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way
first i removed vue modifiers from form tag.
second i chaged type of input from submit to button
and third  this my saveForm function

```
saveForm:function(){
        if (someCondition){
            event.preventDefault();
        }else{
            document.forms[0].submit();
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `prevent` modifier. Another thing, your webpage itself must have the focus. Meaning, if you just visit the webpage, `prevent` won't work. But, if you click somewhere in the form, `prevent` will work for you.

You can still submit the form via JavaScript using something like `document.forms[0].submit();`